# How do I move to a new component after a clock hits zero

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React and Redux app with 3 component sections - Instructions, Story and Quiz - each of the sections has itself 3 sections, so a total of 9 in all. The Instructions have a button that allows the user to progress to the Story section so the transition is easy enough. However, I have a counter that is in the Story component that I need to use to transition to the Quiz component when it hits zero.
Here's my code below

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react'
 import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

 import { connect } from 'react-redux'
 import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
 import { confirmInstructions, enterAnswersMaybeSave, getQuiz, getStory 
 } from '../actions'

 import Instructions from '../components/Instructions'
 import Story from '../components/Story'
 import Quiz from '../components/Quiz/index'

 const App = ({
   errorMessage,
   enterAnswersMaybeSave,
   showInstructions,
   confirmInstructions,
   currentTest,
   kind,
   storyData,
   show,
   timed,
   getQuiz,
   getStory,
   saveQuiz,
   complete,
   enabled,
 }) => {
   if (!currentTest) {
     return (
    <div>
      <p>
        The task is now complete. Thank-you for your time.{' '}
        <a href={window.wordpress.home}>Back to your dashboard</a>.
      </p>
      {errorMessage.length > 0 && <p>{errorMessage}</p>}
    </div>
  )

}
return (
 <div className="test">
   {showInstructions && (
     <Instructions
       currentTest={currentTest}
      confirmInstructions={() => confirmInstructions(currentTest)}
     />
   )}
   {!showInstructions && kind === 'story' && currentTest &&
     (
      <div>
        <Story
          kind='story'
          id={currentTest}
          timed={timed}
          show={show}
          enterAnswers={enterAnswersMaybeSave}
          getQuiz={() => getQuiz(currentTest)}
          complete={complete}


        />
      </div>
       )},
         {!showInstructions && kind === 'quiz' && currentTest &&
         (
           <Quiz
             currentTest={currentTest}
             submit={saveQuiz}
           />
         )}
     </div>
   )
 }


 App.PropTypes = {
   enterAnswersMaybeSave: PropTypes.func,
   showInstructions: PropTypes.bool,
   confirmInstructions: PropTypes.func,
   currentTest: PropTypes.number,
   kind: PropTypes.string, // TODO: enum this
   show: PropTypes.oneOfType([PropTypes.bool, PropTypes.string]),
   timed: PropTypes.number, // TODO: or undefined
   errorMessage: PropTypes.string,
 }
 function mapStateToProps(state) {
   console.log(state.kind); // state
   console.log(arguments[1]); // undefined
 }
 export default connect(
   state => {
     const getCurrent = state => state.storyData.find(t => t.id == 
 state.currentTest);

 const getCurrentStory = state => state.storyData.find(t => t.kind == 
 'story');
     return {
       showInstructions: state.currentTest && 
 !getCurrent(state).instructions,
       currentTest: state.currentTest,
       kind: state.currentTest && getCurrent(state).kind,
       show: state.currentTest && getCurrent(state).show,
       timed: state.currentTest && getCurrent(state).timed,
       answers: state.currentTest && getCurrent(state).answers,
       errorMessage: state.errorMessage,
       complete: state.complete,
       storyData: state.storyData

     }

   },
   dispatch =>
     bindActionCreators({ enterAnswersMaybeSave, confirmInstructions, 
 getQuiz, getStory}, dispatch)
 )(App)
```

> And here's my action-creator

```
   export const getQuiz = payload => ({
        type: GET_QUIZ,
        payload: 'quiz'
      })
```

> And here's my reducer

```
 import { GET_QUIZ } from '../constants/ActionTypes'
 export default (state = [], action) => {
     if (action.type === 'GET_QUIZ') {
       let newState = { ...state, kind: action.payload};
       console.log(newState)
        return newState;
     } else {
       return state
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to store your time in the `redux` store and decrement it using an action that's fired from your timer.

Use that redux prop for the timer in your conditional to determine whether or not the component should be shown. Something like this should work:

```
{this.props.quiz.timer === 0 && renderQuizComponent()}
```

And as long as you have a redux reducer called `quiz` (see https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options), whose values are mapped to the props for your component and an action that decrements the timer and fired on an interval, like:

```
setInterval(this.props.decrementTimer(), 1000);
```

I would recommend doing this properly, calculating the actual time based on a library like MomentJS, but I think that's beyond the scope of this question.

Comment: I tried to do the above but something must not be working. I already had the time decrementing in a nested Clock component that dispatched an action when it hit zero to change the state to "type: 'quiz'. I then added a conditional for the component to render based on the type. But for some reason when the reducer updates the state, it either doesn't re-render the component or it ignores the conditional......

Comment: Have you tried outputting the value of your prop explicitly on the page? Just to be sure it's showing the correct thing. There may be something wrong with the way you've structured your conditionals or the way you're connecting to the redux store within your component. You might want to consider sharing a little more of your code surrounding the interactions with that `type` variable. Additionally, you might want to also consider using `===` instead of `==`. It's generally good practice in React to use strict type comparisons.

Comment: Hmm -- I think there still might be some missing relevant pieces to your code, but at a glance it looks like you're trying to use the same reducer to control the store on many components? Are you expecting `const getCurrent = state => state.storyData.find(t => t.id == 
 state.currentTest);` to return a unique store for each test? Because unless you have it specially mapped somewhere so that that reducer is reimplemented as multiple reducer objects, you may just never be setting the prop that ure expecting in `kind: state.currentTest && getCurrent(state).kind` Do any of those other props work?